# Display Local tasks from one page to another

Tags: 7, routes

I have a menu structure like this:

- $items["foo"] -> MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
- $items["foo/bar"] -> MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK
- $items["foo/something"] -> MENU_LOCAL_TASK
- $items["foo/bar/bazz/%"] -> MENU_CALLBACK

I want to have the tabs (local tasks) from page `foo/bar` displayed on `foo/bar/bazz/%` as well but I don't want to have another local task for this new page.

Any ideas on how can I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda managed to to this by using the following piece of code:

```
$path = drupal_get_normal_path('path-where-local-tasks-are-displayed');
if($path) {
  menu_tree_set_path("navigation", $path);
  menu_set_active_item($path);
}
```

Comment: Hi Marius; 

thanks for the reply.  I can't quite get this to work.  My menu id is 'tasks' and the path mydomain.com/user . So should this code work on my front page for example

    if ($is_front):
    
    $path = drupal_get_normal_path('user');
        if($path) {
          menu_tree_set_path("navigation", $path);
          menu_set_active_item($path);
        }

    endif;

Comment: not quite sure about the user tabs but I think it should be: `$path = drupal_get_normal_path('user/user_id')` and then `menu_tree_set_path("navigation", $path);`